# Need help on sqlite returned: error code =1, msg = table has no column name

Tags: android

I am a beginner on android programming and I'm facing this error trying to insert into my sqlite database.

> sqlite returned: error code =1, msg = table MobileHouseVisit has no column elderly_date_time.

For the first 3 columns there is no problem until I add a few more column. That why I comment it away. I checked the spacing and every thing look alright. I googled about it but still I got no help.

Below is my code

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "silverCareMgt.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "MobileHouseVisit";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase _db;
private final Context context;

public static final String MOBILE_HOUSE_VISIT_ID = "_id";
public static final int COLUMN_KEY_ID = 0;
public static final String ELDERLY_NAME = "elderly_name";
public static final int COLUMN_NAME_ID = 1;
public static final String ELDERLY_NRIC = "elderly_nric";
public static final int COLUMN_TEL_ID = 2;
public static final String ELDERLY_DATE_TIME = "elderly_date_time";
public static final int COLUMN_DT_ID = 3;
//public static final String PHYSICAL_HEALTH_STATUS ="physical_health";
//public static final int COLUMN_PHY_ID = 4;
//public static final String MENTAL_HEALTH_STATUS ="mental_health_status";
//public static final int COLUMN_MENTAL_ID = 5;

protected static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE +" ("+ 
                    MOBILE_HOUSE_VISIT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                    ELDERLY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    ELDERLY_NRIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    ELDERLY_DATE_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"; 
                    //+ PHYSICAL_HEALTH_STATUS + " TEXT, "
                    //+ MENTAL_HEALTH_STATUS + " TEXT);";
```

Comment: you have troubles while creating table or while inserting data into ?

Comment: Try wiping the app data on the phone or uninstalling the app then trying again with all of the columns uncommented.

Comment: how do i do that?? sorry im new .. i have no problem insert data till i uncomment elderly_date_time on wards

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is when you ran your code first time the column was not created in the table.So next time when you added more column to your table db is not created again so is your table. Uninstall your application and then run it again.Database and table will be created again.

Comment: and each time when you release new verions of the app and there are such changes in DB you have to override onUpgrade function and recreate\add you columns in it

Comment: how do i uninstall my application? i using eclipse to do.. sorry im new to all this stuff

Comment: in the emulator goto settings->application->manage application->select your app->uninstall

Comment: you have to delete it from your phone

Comment: thank you very much!! it work.. i clear the data after all :)

Answer (score 0):

The database is created when you run your app for the first time. If you modify the DB you have either to re-install the app thus re-creating your DB or implement [`onUpdgrade`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) method where you take care of the changes to be made to the DB